# Python Stringcompare

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I would like to use wp_scan to scan my wordpress website for new plugins.
I want to have a python script that show me everyday

- a list of vulnerable plugins
- a list of new plugins.

To write a parser which give me only the vulnerable plugins of the output is not complicate. But how I can write a parser (or in which way) so that I get only a list of new plugins.

Example - (source of the example - I modified it a little bit http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/10/14/wpscan-and-quick-wordpress-security/).
First day:

```
___________________________________________________
__          _______   _____
\ \        / /  __ \ / ____|
\ \  /\  / /| |__) | (___   ___  __ _ _ __
\ \/  \/ / |  ___/ \___ \ / __|/ _` | '_ \
\  /\  /  | |     ____) | (__| (_| | | | |
\/  \/   |_|    |_____/ \___|\__,_|_| |_| v2.1rNA
WordPress Security Scanner by the WPScan Team
Sponsored by the RandomStorm Open Source Initiative
_____________________________________________________
| URL: http://www.blackmoreops.com/
| Started on Sun Oct 13 13:39:25 2013
[31m[!][0m The WordPress 'http://www.blackmoreops.com/readme.html' file exists
[31m[!][0m Full Path Disclosure (FPD) in 'http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-includes/rss-functions.php'
[32m[+][0m XML-RPC Interface available under http://www.blackmoreops.com/xmlrpc.php
[32m[+][0m WordPress version 3.6.1 identified from meta generator
[32m[+][0m The WordPress theme in use is twentyten v1.6
| Name: twentyten v1.6
| Location: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/themes/twentyten/
[32m[+][0m Enumerating plugins from passive detection ...
2 plugins found :
| Name: add-to-any v1.2.5
| Location: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/
| Directory listing enabled: Yes
| Readme: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/README.txt
| Name: captcha v3.8.4
| Location: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/captcha/
| Directory listing enabled: Yes
| Readme: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/captcha/readme.txt
[32m[+] Finished at Sun Oct 13 13:39:51 2013[0m
[32m[+] Elapsed time: 00:00:26[0m]
```

on the next day:

```
___________________________________________________
__          _______   _____
\ \        / /  __ \ / ____|
\ \  /\  / /| |__) | (___   ___  __ _ _ __
\ \/  \/ / |  ___/ \___ \ / __|/ _` | '_ \
\  /\  /  | |     ____) | (__| (_| | | | |
\/  \/   |_|    |_____/ \___|\__,_|_| |_| v2.1rNA
WordPress Security Scanner by the WPScan Team
Sponsored by the RandomStorm Open Source Initiative
_____________________________________________________
| URL: http://www.blackmoreops.com/
| Started on Sun Oct 13 13:39:25 2013
[31m[!][0m The WordPress 'http://www.blackmoreops.com/readme.html' file exists
[31m[!][0m Full Path Disclosure (FPD) in 'http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-includes/rss-functions.php'
[32m[+][0m XML-RPC Interface available under http://www.blackmoreops.com/xmlrpc.php
[32m[+][0m WordPress version 3.6.1 identified from meta generator
[32m[+][0m The WordPress theme in use is twentyten v1.6
| Name: twentyten v1.6
| Location: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/themes/twentyten/
[32m[+][0m Enumerating plugins from passive detection ...
3 plugins found :
| Name: add-to-any v1.2.5
| Location: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/
| Directory listing enabled: Yes
| Readme: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/README.txt
| Name: captcha v3.8.4
| Location: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/captcha/
| Directory listing enabled: Yes
| Readme: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/captcha/readme.txt
| Name: google-analyticator v6.4.5
| Location: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/
| Directory listing enabled: Yes
| Readme: http://www.blackmoreops.com/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/readme.txt
[32m[+] Finished at Sun Oct 14 13:39:51 2013[0m
[32m[+] Elapsed time: 00:00:26[0m]
```

Should I separate the string always after a [+] and compare them all 
(I don't know how the list of the output is sorted - I think alpahbetic - so I can't get only the last plugins and say this are my new plugins)? Is that efficient? Making the problem simple:

first string:

```
Hallo
Pet
Me
```

second string:

```
Hallo
World
Pet
Me
```

How I find out what is the new word in a efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you split the string in a list and then print every word in the second string given it is not the first string.

```
    str1 = "Hallo Pet Me"
    str2 = "Hallo World Pet Me"
    split1 = str1.split()
    split2 = str2.split()
    print [word for word in split2 if word not in split1]
```

If you want to ignore differences in lower/uppercase:

```
    str1 = "Hallo Pet Me"
    str2 = "Hallo World Pet Me"
    split1 = str1.lower().split()
    split2 = str2.lower().split()
    print [word for word in split2 if word not in split1]
```

Comment: is it possible to compare two txt if their string is the same?

Answer (score 1):

Solving your simplified example:

```
str1 = "Hallo Pet Me"
str2 = "Hallo World Pet Me"

set1 = set(str1.split())
set2 = set(str2.split())
print set2 - set1
```

You have two sets of strings and you want to obtain strings that are in the second set but not in the first one.

Comment: is it possible to do this with lists? because I save my output as an list.

Comment: @Loretta Just convert the resulting set to the list: `list(set2 - set1)`.